# How to check the order of pressed buttons against an existing array Swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, button

I would like to check the order of pressed buttons(they have all got tags) against an existing array. For example i have an array with 1-9 and 9 buttons, i would like to know if the user is pressing them in the right order. If not then i will return an error. It seems pretty simple but i'm still learning and have exhausted my resources. Thanks in advance!I have managed to make progress and make the buttons print their tags onto the console, but a minor bug seems to occur i cant seem to get them to be all in one array, they are all printed separately.

```
@IBAction func onePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("cell 1 was pressed while it showed \(shuffledArray[0])")
    }
```

This has now been solved! Thanks for all the help! Here is the working code!

```
 @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //print("cell  was pressed while it showed \(shuffledArray[0])")

    switch(sender.tag){

    case 1:
        order.add(sender.tag)//adding to nsmutable array use add or at a specific index use insert
        print(order)
        self.oneLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 2:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.twoLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 3:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.threeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 4:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.fourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 5:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.fiveLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 6:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.sixLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 7:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.sevenLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 8:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.eightLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    case 9:
        order.add(sender.tag)
        print(order)
        self.nineLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    default :
        break
    }

    if order.count == 9 {
        print(order.count)
        let indexOfShuffled = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        let combined = zip(shuffledArray, indexOfShuffled).sorted {$0.0 < $1.0}
        print(combined)

        // use map to extract the individual arrays
        let sortedIndexOfShuffled = combined.map {$0.1}
        let sortedShuffledArray = combined.map {$0.0}

        print(sortedIndexOfShuffled)  // "[1.2, 1.5, 2.4, 10.9, 20.0]"
        print(sortedShuffledArray)  // "[1, 3, 0, 0, 2]"

        if order == sortedIndexOfShuffled as! NSMutableArray{
            self.oneLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.twoLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.threeLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.fourLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.fiveLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.sixLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.sevenLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.eightLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
            self.nineLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick.png"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            self.oneLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.twoLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.threeLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.fourLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.fiveLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.sixLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.sevenLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.eightLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
            self.nineLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with using this instead (change Any to UIButton -- assuming you are using a button here, if not, use your actual type)

```
@IBAction func onePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("cell 1 was pressed while it showed \(shuffledArray[0])")
}
```

Then

```
if sender.tag == shuffledArray[0] {
  // the button's tag is the first one in the array
}
```

You might want to keep an index (instead of using 0 above)

Add a property

```
var buttonPressedIndex = 0
```

Then

```
if sender.tag == shuffledArray[buttonPressedIndex] {
  // the button's tag is the next one in the array
  buttonPressedIndex += 1 // go to next button in array
} else {
  // show an error
}
```